# Find a max possible value of an undefined function in an interval when derivative is a constant

Tags: extreme-value-theorem

The function $f(x)$ is continuous and differentiable in $[0,1]$
if $f'(x)\le 10$ for all $x\in[0,1]$ and $f(0)=0$,

What is the maximum possible value of $f(x)$ for $x\in [0,1]$ ?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Just apply Mean Value Theorem.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE. Questions like yours that don't include the authors own work/thoughts are unpopular here, and tend to get closed quite fast. You should edit the question to include that. When editing the question you should also use some MathJax (LaTeX) for formatting, the help center has links to get you started with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\forall x\in [0,1]$ we have,

$\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}\le 10$ {By lagrange's mean value theorem we have a $c\in [0,x]\ such\ that\ \frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}=f'(c)\le10$}

$\therefore$ maximum value of f(x) is 10$x$ in [0,1].

Hope it helps:)